# Remove extra spaces and curly braces latex code in string Python (normalize string in python)

Tags: strings, python

I want to normalize string in python. For example, I have a LaTeX code

```
str='{{{       \\dfrac{{3}}{{4}}    +   \\sqrt{3} }}}'
```

I want to get the string

```
str='{\\dfrac{3}{4}+\\sqrt{3}}'
```

Remove extra spaces and curly braces (ex: `{{3}}-->{3}`,... )

Please, help me! Thanks!

Comment: this seems to be a purely python regex question I'm not sure it's on topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the regexp more complicated to catch more deeply nested cases, and this will lose some significant white space such as `\mbox{ }` but....

```
import re
v=r"str='{{{       \\dfrac{{3}}{{4}}    +   \\sqrt{3} }}}'"
v=re.sub('([^a-zA-Z]) +', r'\1',v)
v2=re.sub('{{(([^{}]|{[^{}]*})*)}}',r'{\1}',v)
while v2 != v:
    v=v2
    v2=re.sub('{{(([^{}]|{[^{}]*})*)}}',r'{\1}',v)
print(v)
```

produces

```
str='{\\dfrac{3}{4}+\\sqrt{3}}'
```